# Postgres Raise warning if count is 0

Tags: postgresql

I am very new to postgres and i need to truncate table if there is any record otherwise I need to raise WARNING .I am trying to do the following :

```
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE public."BINARY";
EXCEPTION
    WHEN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  public."BINARY" THEN RAISE NOTICE 'There is no record present in table.';
END;
```

But the above code is not working.Can anyone please suggest me ,what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `exception` is used to _catch_ [an exception](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) in a stored procedure or function, not to throw one. And it can't be used in plain SQL. But what's the actual problem you are trying to solve? The table will be empty after the TRUNCATE anyway and truncating an empty table isn't an error. So just truncate the table and forget about the rest

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: apologies for confusion.FIrst I need to check if table count is 0 and if result is false then I need to do truncate>HOwever I foiund the solution.Just posting it.Thanks for your help

Comment: So why the check at all? If the table isempty before the truncate, then it will be empty afterwards. If it's not empty, it will be after the truncate. The check seems completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is PL/pgSQL code for what you want:

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM atable) = 0 THEN
   RAISE WARNING 'table is empty';
ELSE
   TRUNCATE atable;
END IF;
```

But I don't quite see the point.